# Pointer to array of Structures

Tags: java, jna

Consider I have the following C struct definitions:

```
struct StructA {
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct StructB {
    struct A *as;
    int count;
};
```

So, the `as` field of `StructB` points to an array of `StructA`'s of size `count`. Then, I represent `struct StructA` in Java with the following class:

```
public class StructA extends Structure {
    public int a;
    public int b;

    public StructA() {

    }

    public StructA(Pointer p) {
        super(p);
        read();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[]{"a", "b"});
    }
    public static class Reference extends StructA implements Structure.ByReference { }
    public static class Value extends StructA implements Structure.ByValue { }
}
```

But, how would I represent `struct B` in Java? Since `as` is not a inline array, I would have to represent `as` as a `Pointer`, so how would I turn a Java `StructA[]` into a `Pointer`?

Comment: What's the problem on having StructA[] or ArrayList<StructA> or whatever? It's still a reference, any changes you make to the items on the array propagate to the original class.

Comment: Or better yet, simply replace StructB with an ArrayList, which does all that StructB does.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that the field has pointer type.  You can do this with `Structure.ByReference` (make a subclass of your structure class which implements the `Structure.ByReference` tagging interface) and then use `Structure.toArray()` to overlay a contiguous array of struct over that memory.

You can also just use a simple `Pointer`, but then you'll need to manually read/write the structure and related objects, as well as do native memory synchronization that JNA normally does for you.

For example:

```
class StructA {
    public static class ByReference extends StructA implements Structure.ByReference { }
}
class StructB {
   public StructA.ByReference sa;
   public int size;
   public StructA[] getMembers() {
       return (StructA[])sa.toArray(this.size);
   }
}
```